# Blender 3 and up won't open on m1mac monterey

Tags: installation

[image]

Previous version worked fine.
I cannot open 3.01 or get the latest betas to open at all. The error image above appears immediately.
GHOST_ContextCGL::metallnit:newLibraryWithSource:options:error:failed!

Any suggestions please?!

Comment: are u sure u downloaded the right version? for m1? Apple Silikon is the right one.

Comment: I have the same problem. Blender 3.01 was working, and I tried to upgrade to 3.1 to try a package that needed it. Started getting this error, and now no versions work -- same error on 3.01, two 3.1 betas, and 3.2 alpha.

There's no crash report because it's not actually a crash -- just this error window that then forces you to exit. Definitely frustrating -- can anyone suggest anything else to try?

Yes, these are apple silicon builds. I'm on a 2021 14" MBP running Monterey.

I opened a ticket in the blender forums here: https://developer.blender.org/T95844 

Thanks in advance ~~

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I was having the same problem. At the suggestion of the blender dev forum, I upgraded my OS from 12.0 to 12.2.1, and the issue is now resolved. Hooray!